# Calculating average of a vector with a for loop C++

Tags: c++

Currently doing an introduction course to c++, need to use a loop to read values from file to a vector, print that to console. This I've been able to do but, then I need to use a for-loop to find the average. I may be reading other code that I've looked at for clues... But can't seem to find much help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream numbers;
    numbers.open("G:\\numbers.dat"); // just a file of 10 integers.
    int i;
    vector<float> vectors;

    while(numbers >> i) {
        vectors.push_back(i);
    }

    for(int n=0; n < vectors.size(); ++n ){
        cout << vectors[n] << endl;
    }

    int avg;
    for(int k=0; k < vectors.size(); ++k){
        // not sure what to put here basically.
        cout << avg << endl;
    }


    numbers.close();

    return 0;
}
```

any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is an average? You are looping through the vector... you are accessing all of the numbers, how would you average a set of numbers? P.S. one thing to note, if you divide an integer by an integer, you'll get an integer result which will be a truncated (floor) operation rather than a proper rounding operation.

Comment: Do you know how to compute an average by hand?

Comment: if you want to keep this question going, please do not call your vector "vectors" - that's a very confusing naming convention, and a bad example to people learning.  It might be best to call it "elements" or something like that.  Then the answers will become more useful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average is the sum of the elements divided by number of elements. So:

```cpp
    int avg;
    int sumTotal = 0;
    for(int k=0; k < vectors.size(); ++k){
        // not sure what to put here basically.
        sumTotal += vectors[k];            
    }
    avg = sumTotal / vectors.size();
    cout << avg << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, not sure why I hadn't got it. Much appreciated.

Comment: please set question as Answered, so no other used loose time in that ;)

Comment: you answered to quickly said I needed to wait 5 minutes, then got distracted haha its done now...

Answer (score 1):

note that in Tirma's solution there's a problem with the index in the for loop. it's supposed to be k, not n.

also note that we can also use auto-based loop instead of the described for loop:

```
for (int vector: vectors)
{
    sumTotal+= vector;
}
```